# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error occurs in Django

Tags: python, django

IM NEW TO PYTHON I HAVE DOWNLOADED THIS PYTHON FROM GITHUB AND I GET THIS ERROR WHEN I RUN IT
[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Nk6.png)
IT SAYS RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
users has no faculty

can some one solve the problem and post the correct code to execute the program
I am still new to the language please solve the error as soon as possible

model.py code

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist


def user_directory_path(instance, filename): 
    name, ext = filename.split(".")
    name = instance.firstname + instance.lastname
    filename = name +'.'+ ext 
    return 'Faculty_Images/{}'.format(filename)

class Faculty(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, blank = True, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path ,null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.firstname + " " + self.lastname)


def student_directory_path(instance, filename): 
    name, ext = filename.split(".")
    name = instance.registration_id # + "_" + instance.branch + "_" + instance.year + "_" + instance.section
    filename = name +'.'+ ext 
    return 'Student_Images/{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(instance.branch,instance.year,instance.section,filename)

class Student(models.Model):

    BRANCH = (
        ('CSE','CSE'),
        ('IT','IT'),
        ('ECE','ECE'),
        ('CHEM','CHEM'),
        ('MECH','MECH'),
        ('EEE','EEE'),
    )
    YEAR = (
        ('1','1'),
        ('2','2'),
        ('3','3'),
        ('4','4'),
    )
    SECTION = (
        ('A','A'),
        ('B','B'),
        ('C','C'),
    )

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    registration_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=BRANCH)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=YEAR)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=SECTION)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=student_directory_path ,null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.registration_id)

class Attendence(models.Model):
    # faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty, null = True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    # student = models.ForeignKey(Student, null = True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    Faculty_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Student_ID = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True, null = True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True, null = True)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    period = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True, default='Absent')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Student_ID + "_" + str(self.date)+ "_" + str(self.period))
```

view.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, StreamingHttpResponse

from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


from .forms import *
from .models import Student, Attendence
from .filters import AttendenceFilter

# from django.views.decorators import gzip

from .recognizer import Recognizer
from datetime import date

@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def home(request):
    studentForm = CreateStudentForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        studentForm = CreateStudentForm(data = request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        # print(request.POST)
        stat = False 
        try:
            student = Student.objects.get(registration_id = request.POST['registration_id'])
            stat = True
        except:
            stat = False
        if studentForm.is_valid() and (stat == False):
            studentForm.save()
            name = studentForm.cleaned_data.get('firstname') +" " +studentForm.cleaned_data.get('lastname')
            messages.success(request, 'Student ' + name + ' was successfully added.')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Student with Registration Id '+request.POST['registration_id']+' already exists.')
            return redirect('home')

    context = {'studentForm':studentForm}
    return render(request, 'attendence_sys/home.html', context)


def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        
        user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or Password is incorrect')

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'attendence_sys/login.html', context)

@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')

@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def updateStudentRedirect(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            reg_id = request.POST['reg_id']
            branch = request.POST['branch']
            student = Student.objects.get(registration_id = reg_id, branch = branch)
            updateStudentForm = CreateStudentForm(instance=student)
            context = {'form':updateStudentForm, 'prev_reg_id':reg_id, 'student':student}
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'Student Not Found')
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'attendence_sys/student_update.html', context)

@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def updateStudent(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context = {}
        try:
            student = Student.objects.get(registration_id = request.POST['prev_reg_id'])
            updateStudentForm = CreateStudentForm(data = request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance = student)
            if updateStudentForm.is_valid():
                updateStudentForm.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Updation Success')
                return redirect('home')
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'Updation Unsucessfull')
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'attendence_sys/student_update.html', context)


@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def takeAttendence(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        details = {
            'branch':request.POST['branch'],
            'year': request.POST['year'],
            'section':request.POST['section'],
            'period':request.POST['period'],
            'faculty':request.user.faculty,
            }
        if Attendence.objects.filter(date = str(date.today()),branch = details['branch'], year = details['year'], section = details['section'],period = details['period']).count() != 0 :
            messages.error(request, "Attendence already recorded.")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            students = Student.objects.filter(branch = details['branch'], year = details['year'], section = details['section'])
            names = Recognizer(details)
            for student in students:
                if str(student.registration_id) in names:
                    attendence = Attendence(Faculty_Name = request.user.faculty,
                    Student_ID = str(student.registration_id), 
                    period = details['period'], 
                    branch = details['branch'], 
                    year = details['year'], 
                    section = details['section'],
                    status = 'Present')
                    attendence.save()
                else:
                    attendence = Attendence(Faculty_Name = request.user.faculty, 
                    Student_ID = str(student.registration_id), 
                    period = details['period'],
                    branch = details['branch'], 
                    year = details['year'], 
                    section = details['section'])
                    attendence.save()
            attendences = Attendence.objects.filter(date = str(date.today()),branch = details['branch'], year = details['year'], section = details['section'],period = details['period'])
            context = {"attendences":attendences, "ta":True}
            messages.success(request, "Attendence taking Success")
            return render(request, 'attendence_sys/attendence.html', context)        
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'attendence_sys/home.html', context)

def searchAttendence(request):
    attendences = Attendence.objects.all()
    myFilter = AttendenceFilter(request.GET, queryset=attendences)
    attendences = myFilter.qs
    context = {'myFilter':myFilter, 'attendences': attendences, 'ta':False}
    return render(request, 'attendence_sys/attendence.html', context)


def facultyProfile(request):
    faculty = request.user.faculty,
    form = FacultyForm(instance = faculty)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'attendence_sys/facultyForm.html', context)



# class VideoCamera(object):
#     def __init__(self):
#         self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#     def __del__(self):
#         self.video.release()

#     def get_frame(self):
#         ret,image = self.video.read()
#         ret,jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg',image)
#         return jpeg.tobytes()


# def gen(camera):
#     while True:
#         frame = camera.get_frame()
#         yield(b'--frame\r\n'
#         b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')


# @gzip.gzip_page
# def videoFeed(request):
#     try:
#         return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(VideoCamera()),content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
#     except:
#         print("aborted")

# def getVideo(request):
#     return render(request, 'attendence_sys/videoFeed.html')
```

Comment: Please don't use *all caps*, it is seen as screaming. Posts should not try to draw more attention, often that will also work counterproductive anyway.

Comment: As for the error, it is not a problem with the view, but with the data: you did not add a `Faculty` fo the student. However the modeling looks *strange* to say the least, not to say "ugly"...

Comment: can you please share the write the code as i said still im beginner to this language

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As clearly stated by the error, you access `request.user.faculty` but user has no faculty

You can use a try excetp statement to handle the error properly

```py
try:
    faculty = request.user.faculty
except RelatedObjectDoesNotExist as e:
    # handle error
```

Comment: can you please tell me the in which line should i add this